# Appending div into Struts2 action response in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, struts2, yui

I'm using YUI and Struts2 to show an interactive application. I need a div to be updated once an *onchange* event is triggered. This is the code i'm using:

```
<div id="...">
    <s:form id="..." action="...">
        <s:select id="proyecto_actual_select" .../>
    </s:form>
    <sx:bind sources="proyecto_actual_select" formId="cambiar_proyecto_actual_form" targets="pantalla_principal" events="onchange" afterNotifyTopics="cambioProyecto"/>
</div>
```

After the action is performed, this script is executed:

```
YUI({combine: false, filter: 'raw'}).use('bezier-wire', 'container','image-container',function(Y) {

    window.Y = Y;
    var layerEl = Y.one('#pantalla_principal');

    ...Some changes on layerEl...
};
```

When Struts2 renders the div *pantalla_principal*, the div is shown without the changes performed on him during the script. What should i do to get that div to be exactly like layerE1?

Comment: Does this have *anything* to do with jQuery?

Comment: I figured the solution should be jQuery based since i'm appending a div into the response.

Comment: @AymanSafadi funny when reading the title I was thinking "How does this have anything to do with struts2?"?

Comment: I would prefer it if you did not use those struts2 ajax tags, they hide details from people who could otherwise help. We can not determine what you need to do because there are two possible scenarios: 1) You need to add the data from an ajax request 2) You are dynamically extending a form and don't need any server side involvement. The two are very different, so we need more details. If 1 I can help with the process of sending the data, if 2, use jquery like any typical client side programmer would and you'll find a lot of help.